# Extreme Pattern for Lists in Python

Tags: python

I'm supposed to find the smallest value in a list of nodes using the "extreme pattern for nodes." I am not allowed to use the `min()` function. I think I need to use a loop or recursion of some sort. Here is the "extreme pattern" for arrays:

```
    largest = items[0]
    for i in range(0,len(items),1):
        if (items[i] > largest):
            largest = items[i]
```

But this pattern will not work on lists like this one which contains nodes:

```
    [1, [23, [53, [54, [5, None]]]]]
```

How do I implement a similar pattern to find the smallest value in a list like the one above?

Comment: This sounds like a fun problem to have!  What ideas do you have?  Recursion is a good start, what have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
curList = items
if curList:
    largest = items[0]
    while curList is not None:
        if (curList[0] > largest):
            largest = curList[0]
        curList = curList[1]
    print largest
```

Comment: Thanks for your speedy reply! Awesome.

Comment: I had to change it just a little though:

Comment: it is incorrect (lines 3,4,5). See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13467789/4279)

Answer (score 3):

```
def myMin(mylist):
    smallest = float('inf')
    for l in mylist:
        if isinstance(l,list):
            tmp = myMin(l)
            if tmp < smallest:
                smallest = tmp
        elif l < smallest:
            smallest = l
    if smallest == float('inf'):
        return None
    return smallest
```

Fixed on @Blckknght's comments.

Comment: This won't work in Python 3, since None is not comparable to objects of any other type. You're also missing a `return largest` at the end! (Also, you're calculating the max, not the min, so the function name is misleading.)

Comment: Fixed! This is why you shouldn't code early in the morning. Also testing.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a variation on @aw4lly's answer, which will work in Python 3.

```
def myMin(lst):
    smallest = None
    for i in lst:
        if isinstance(i, list):
            i = myMin(i)
        if smallest is None or i is not None and i < smallest:
            smallest = i
    return smallest
```

This can handle any sort of nested list, including ones that are partially or completely empty (where for our purposes an empty list is one with no members except other "empty" lists). Empty lists return `None` as their minimum, which isn't exactly the same as Python's standard `min` function (but it makes the recursion a bit easier).

```
>>> print(myMin([1, 2, 3, [4, [5], [], 0, [6, 7]], [[8], 9]]))
0
>>> print(myMin([[[],[[],[],[[],[]],]],[],[[]]]))
None
```

Answer (score 1):

```
car = lambda lst: lst[0]  # value
cdr = lambda lst: lst[1]  # next list

lst = items
if lst:  # not empty
   largest = car(lst)
   while lst is not None:
         if largest < car(lst):
            largest = car(lst)
         lst = cdr(lst)
   print(largest)
```

[example](http://ideone.com/NuNcV0)